# Skyrim Requirement - List your Console

Tags: discussion

Many questions have been asked about various bugs and ways to get around them. Everyone knows that the PC has a Console where you can do pretty much everything, such as placing 20 Dragon Priests in Whiterun and watch everyone non-essential die. Skyrim, while it is a good game, does have bugs.

Depending on if the person has a PC or a Console, I may have a different answer to the question; usually I will be able to help a PC with a bug via console, but way less likely with a 360/PS3.

I propose that to make answering these questions easier, anyone who asks a question about a Skyrim bug (possibly other multi-platform games as well) be **encouraged** to state what console they are playing on, whether by tag or by wording in question.

Comment: If they don't mention it in their question, you can definitely use a comment to ask them to specify.  If there are different solutions, it also helps to include all of them in your answer.

Comment: @bwarner - having played the PS3 and PC version - I have encountered bugs in both that I have been able to use console commands in PC to fix. As for the PS3, there might be a way, but I am way less likely to know it (of course I would post it if I did).

Comment: @tehdoommarine Well then provide the solution that you're able to. There's a reason that our engine provides for questions to have multiple answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the problem is system-specific (in which case the tags would be warranted), it's better to provide solutions for all the systems if you can. After all, others with the same problem but a different system will then find the question and, by extension, your answer will be significantly more useful.

If you can only provide solution for a specific platform, that's fine too - state in the answer which platform your answer pertains to and leave the other variants to other's answers. You might not get the same reputation initially as someone who guesses the gaming system of the original question asker, but your answer will be useful nonetheless - to others who have the same problem, but on a different system.